# Spring Boot, JPA, OrderForm

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I want to make an orderform with spring boot where I can Save the order with more order items.
I dont't know how to implement the Service, Class and even the thymeleaf page for this.
Any hint would be great!
Here's a picture what I want to make

[image]

An here's my two entity class(no getters and setters, and customer for brevity)

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_item")
public class OrderItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private Order order;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;
    
    private int qty;
    private double amount;
    
    
    public OrderItem() {}
    
    public OrderItem(int id, Order order, Product product, int qty, double amount) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.order = order;
        this.product = product;
        this.qty = qty;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @Entity
@Table(name="order")
public class Order {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    private Date dateTime;
    private double total;
    private int paidStatus;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
    private Customers customer;
    

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customOrder")
    private List<OrderItem> orderItems;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to create a repository, service and controller.

**1. First, let's create repositories for our models.**

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {}
```

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {}
```

```
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {}
```

**2. Second, let's create our service layer.**
(Note: I gathered all the functionality here for an example.You can distribute it to different layers.)

```
public interface OrderService {
    List<Customer> findAllCustomers();
    List<Product> findAllProducts();
    List<Order> findAllOrders();
}
```

```
@Service
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {

    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    private final ProductRepository productRepository;
    private final OrderRepository orderRepository;

    public OrderServiceImpl(CustomerRepository customerRepository,
                            ProductRepository productRepository,
                            OrderRepository orderRepository) {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Customer> findAllCustomers() {
        return customerRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Product> findAllProducts() {
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Order> findAllOrders() {
        return orderRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**3. Now add a controller layer, this will reply to your urls.** (Note: here are simple examples just to help you understand the operation. You can come up with many different solutions.)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/order")
public class OrderController {

    private final OrderService orderService;

    public OrderController(OrderService orderService) {
        this.orderService = orderService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/create")
    public String createOrder(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("customers", orderService.findAllCustomers());
        model.addAttribute("products", orderService.findAllProducts());
        model.addAttribute("order", new Order());
        return "order-form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/insert")
    public String insertOrder(Model model, Order order) {
        // Save operations ..
        return "order-view";
    }
}
```

**4. Here, customers and products come from your database.**

The 'Submit Form' button will be sending the entity id's of the selections here to the `insertOrder` method. (You can duplicate your other fields in a similar way and I recommend you to examine the example in [this link](https://vkuzel.com/add-or-remove-items-from-a-list-of-objects-in-a-model-attribute-using-spring-mvc-and-thymeleaf) to dynamically duplicate this product selection area.)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
<div>
    <form action="/order/insert" method="post" th:object="${order}">
        <p>
            <label>Select Customer</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <select name="customer.id">
                <option th:each="customer : ${customers}"
                        th:value="${customer.id}"
                        th:text="${customer.name}">Customer Name</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Select Product</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <select name="orderItems[0].product.id">
                <option th:each="product : ${products}"
                        th:value="${product.id}"
                        th:text="${product.name}">Product Name</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" name="orderItems[0].quantity" />
        </p>
        <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I recommend you to [read this example](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa), which has scope for necessary library and spring settings.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was really helpful!